# Converting between vectors and dual vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm trying to understand how to convert between vectors and dual vectors.

Notation:
I represent vectors with upper indices and dual vectors with lower indices. I use the metric tensor for special relativity, which I denote by $\eta_{\mu \nu}$. This metric is a 4x4 matrix with diagonal components -1, 1, 1, 1 and off-diagonal components being zero.

If I want to represent a vector as a dual vector, I know that
$$V^\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}V_\nu$$, but as I have understood dual vectors are represented as row matrices (and vectors as column matrices) so you cannot take the matrix product of the matrix and the dual vector, as the first matrix should have as many columns as the second one has rows.

Furthermore, going other way around doesn't make sense to me either. If
$$V_\mu=\eta_{\mu \nu}V^\nu$$
, then the right-hand side of the equation would give a column matrix, which would be associated with a regular vector, not a dual vector.

Comment: What exactly is $\eta$ in this context?

Comment: The metric. For special relativity, it is 4x4 matrix with diagonal terms -1, 1, 1, 1 and off-diagonal terms being zero.

Comment: @VilleAlanko please consider adding those relevant details to the question body.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Got it, I'm actually brand new to this site so forgive me for any blunders :D.

Comment: Are you trying to associate the upper indices with columns and the lower ones as rows? That doesn't quite work, otherwise you'd have $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ as a 4 times 1 matrix or something.

Comment: The notation is from a book on general relativity (from special relativity section). I'm not exactly trying to associate upper indices with columns and lower indicies with rows; I'm associating vectors with upper indices and vectors happen to be column matrices. The metric is a tensor so I guess none of this applies to it. I have just taken it as granted when the book gave me the expression for the metric :D.

Comment: Objects which take a column vector and return a column vector have an upper and a lower index. $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ has two lower indices, though. It takes a column vector and returns a row vector.

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$V_\mu=\eta_{\mu\nu}V^\nu$$
can be written in matrix form as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}V_0 \\ V_1 \\ V_2 \\ V_3 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}V^0 \\ V^1 \\ V^2 \\ V^3 \end{bmatrix}
$$
or equivalently as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}V_0 & V_1 & V_2 & V_3 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}V^0 & V^1 & V^2 & V^3 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In all three cases the equation simply tells you how to calculate $V_0$, $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$.
\begin{align*}
V_0&= -V^0 \\
V_1&= V^1 \\
V_2&= V^2 \\
V_3&= V^3 \\
\end{align*}
After you calculate them you can put them in a row matrix if you want
$$\begin{bmatrix}V_0 & V_1 & V_2 & V_3 \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}-V^0 & V^1 & V^2 & V^3 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Matrices are just a notation which is sometimes convenient to perform certain calculations. You seem to think that whenever an indexed object $V^\mu$ has upper indices it should be written as a column and it is prohibited to write it as a row (and viceversa with $V\mu$), or at least that is what I got from your question. This is not the case, both notations carry the same information, you just write them however you need to perform your calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm new to the subject so I wasn't comfortable writing the column matrices as row matrices, but I guess it works out.